# Combine two JSON by addition python 2.7

Tags: python, json

I want to combine two JSON which have the same form and increment the differents array which already exists in one JSON :
JSON a :

```
[
    {
        "productTitle": "Product1",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 1
        },
        "totalCalls": 1
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product2",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 1,
            "api2": 2,
            "api3": 3,
            "api4": 4
        },
        "totalCalls": 10
    }

]
```

JSON b:

```
[
    {
        "productTitle": "Product1",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 1
        },
        "totalCalls": 1
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product2",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 1,
            "api2": 2,
            "api3": 3,
            "api4": 4
        },
        "totalCalls": 10
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product3",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2
        },
        "totalCalls": 2
    }

]
```

To obtain something like this :

```
[
    {
        "productTitle": "Product1",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2
        },
        "totalCalls": 2
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product2",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2,
            "api2": 4,
            "api3": 6,
            "api4": 8
        },
        "totalCalls": 20
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product3",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2
        },
        "totalCalls": 2
    }

]
```

I try to combine them using a previous script I used where I compare the existing JSON to a dataList(which here is our second JSON) like this :

```
import json

with open('testa.json') as json_data:
    json_a = json.load(json_data)

with open('testb.json') as json_data:
    json_b = json.load(json_data)

with open('outputMerge.json', 'w') as f:

    data_list = json_a
    for data in json_b:
        title = data["productTitle"] #get all product title
        exist = False

        for existing_data in data_list: #loop in data_list
            if data["api-activity"] in existing_data["api-activity"]:
                print ("true")
```

but I have an error with the differents keys I use :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge.py", line 17, in 
    if data["api-activity"] in existing_data["api-activity"]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Can you help me debugging I think I'm close or if you have a better solution maybe ?

Comment: Your JSON does not contain a dict with the key ``apiName``, so of course you get a ``KeyError: 'apiName'`` - what did you expect?

Comment: Ok, I edit it, I'm looking for a way to addition the value of the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by loading your counts into a `Counter()` object, using the tuple `(title, api)` as the key. This can then be converted back into an output dictionary, for example:

```
Counter({('Product2', 'api4'): 8, ('Product2', 'api3'): 6, ('Product2', 'api2'): 4, ('Product1', 'api1'): 2, ('Product2', 'api1'): 2, ('Product3', 'api1'): 2})
```

This can be done as follows:

```
from collections import Counter            
from itertools import groupby
import json

api_counts = Counter()

def update_counters(json_filename):
    with open(json_filename) as f_json:
        for product in json.load(f_json):
            title = product['productTitle']
            api_counts.update({(title, api) : count for api, count in product['api-activity'].items()})

update_counters('testa.json')
update_counters('testb.json')

output = []

for product, apis in groupby(sorted(api_counts.items()), lambda x: x[0][0]):
    api_activity = {}
    total_calls = 0

    for (p, api), count in apis:
        api_activity[api] = count
        total_calls += count

    output.append({'productTitle': product, 'api-activity' : api_activity, 'totalCalls' : total_calls})

with open('outputMerge.json', 'w') as f_output:
    json.dump(output, f_output, indent=4)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
[
    {
        "productTitle": "Product1",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2
        },
        "totalCalls": 2
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product2",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2,
            "api2": 4,
            "api3": 6,
            "api4": 8
        },
        "totalCalls": 20
    },
    {
        "productTitle": "Product3",
        "api-activity": {
            "api1": 2
        },
        "totalCalls": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! thanks ! About the groupby, I don't get what you did with the lambda and how it works ?

Comment: It tells `groupby()` to group on the product. The output from `api_counts.items()` would be of the form `(('Product1', 'api1'), 2)` so `x[0][0]` extracts `Product1`